# How Paypal works in a failover

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, paypal

I am working for a customer that has the following architecture:

- Back End

  - Java Server
- Front End

  - Proxy (Node JS + Express application)

All the requests that we make to the server needs to go through the Proxy (security feature).

We need to integrate Paypal API in our application, so we have created two actions for OK and KO callbacks (let's say `/proxy/paymentOK` and `/proxy/paymentKO`) that calls our server and update the status of a record.

Now is the time for our problems:

- Let's say that a user makes a payment. So, paypal will call our OK callback (`/proxy/paymentOK`). If a problem appears between proxy and server (for example, power or network failure), what happens with the payment? The payment will be returned to the customer automatically? How Paypal knows that everything goes fine after make the call?
- Before send  the paypal request I will persist some values, so I have an ID for a record with status `PENDING_PAYMENT`. Paypal needs to know this parameter, because whether payment accepts or rejects, I have to update the record with `ACCEPTED`or `REFUSED` status. How can I send this ID to Paypal and how can a get it when Paypal makes the callback?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Long time I havent dive into paypal, but you should have a *Transaction_ID* and it allows you to check the status of a transaction at anytime. If something goes wrong, you can check every pending transaction status that you have and continue the process from where it breaks.

Comment: @cyrbill, but I will receive that Transaction_ID as response after call Paypal API?

Answer (score 2):

The process goes like this:

1. #### Create a payment

   This just declare the detail about the transaction but does not engage the user into a payment. The payment can be edited as many time as you want until step 2. You will receive an ID and urls for this payment.
2. #### User pay

   You give the user the url for the transaction, user pay. You get notified (you should not trust the OK/KO callbacks, just the payment id).
3. #### Approve payment

   You check the payment status and if it's in pending state, you execute/approve it. The transaction is complete.

If you crash **step 1**, nothing to worries, the transaction did not even start. You can safely start another one.

If you crash **step 2**, when starting the server back you have all your payment Ids and *should* do the step 3 for every one of them.

If you crash **step 3**, you can safely redo it, paypal will informs you that this payment have been executed or not and gives you its status.

*Notice:* that even if you lost information, you can retrieve it at anytime. ([List payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#list-payment-resources) or get a [payment informations](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#look-up-a-payment-resource))

Comment: Thanks @cybil for your answer. I would like that step 3 were more automatic, but it looks that is impossible :(.

Comment: Their is other methods for end of step 2 (the notification part) that are more direct but you still need to approve the payment. Step 1 is you and user debating the price and items. Step 2 is the user dropping money on the table. Step 3 is you taking the money. As you see, the buying is not done until step 3. And if you found money on the table, you will have to find which client dropped it and for what items :)